# Dynamic SOQL query relationship with field visibility for Users

Tags: apex, soql

I created a dynamic SOQL query method and I am curious about what will happen if the user that triggers the code does not have access to the field. Will the entire org start receiving errors?

```
public with sharing class QuerySelector {

    public static List<SObject> dynamicQuerySelector(Set<Id> idSet) {

        // check if null

        List<SObject> sObjectList = new List<SObject>();

        if(idSet.size() > 0)
        {
            // convert the set to a list
            List<Id> idList = new List<Id>(idSet);


            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sor = idList[0].getSobjectType().getDescribe();
            String recObject = String.valueOf(sor.getName());

            Set<String> fieldNames = sor.fields.getMap().keySet();

            String recordQuery = 'SELECT ' + String.join(new List<String>(fieldNames),',') + ' FROM ' + recObject + ' WHERE id in :idSet ';

            sObjectList = Database.query(recordQuery);

            return sObjectList;
        }
        return sObjectList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Apex can query all fields--even if the user can't see those fields. This can produce a situation where data is leaked to the user that they should not see. No errors or exceptions would occur (other than possibly due to too many fields/LOB fields/etc).

There's a new beta feature ([WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_enforced.htm#apex_classes_with_security_enforced)) to prevent this data leakage, but the tradeoff is that the query will fail with an exception. For this reason, among others, you should not describe an entire object this way, or at minimum, you should check the field's describe calls to see if they are accessible to the current user.